# PHP error while using array

Tags: php, arrays

I get this error from the first line of the following code:

```
    Fatal error: Only variables can be passed by reference in /home/path/file.php on line 36



        if (isset($_POST['id']))
        {
            $ids = array_walk('intval', $_POST['id']);

            $sql = "DELETE FROM table WHERE id IN (' . implode(',', $ids) . ')')";
            //run query here

            $msg->type = "success";
            $msg->text = "Bulk delete has been successful";
        }
```

Any ideas what it could be?

BTW, the above code is to mass delete items.

Error is caused by `$ids = array_walk('intval', $_POST['id']);`

Comment: use double quotes in this line instead:
"DELETE FROM table WHERE id IN (" . implode(',', $ids) . ")')";

Comment: Do you have an empty value in one of your id's?

Comment: have you got the parameters on array_walk in the wrong order?

Comment: @AndreasStokholm The issue is with the `$ids = array_walk('intval', $_POST['id']);` line

Comment: @Scuzzy what do you mean? The $_POST['id'] is empty, I moved it inside the if statement (updated the Q), but I still get the error.

Comment: Someone nailed the answer, but they removed it! it way array_map that solved my issues.

Comment: @user962449 Exactly, I assume you have an array in $_POST['id'] since you walk through it. If one of the array entries have a key but no value, will it not fail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your call to the function `array_walk` is incorrect

```
bool array_walk ( array &$array , callback $funcname [, mixed $userdata = NULL ] )
```

try this instead and assuming that `$_POST['id']` is an array

```
$ids = array_walk($_POST['id'], 'intval');
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php

Also it may be good to check before calling the function to make sure that `$_POST['id']` is an array

**EDIT**

After looking at what you doing a little more the function you need to use is `array_map`.  `array_walk` returns a boolean while `array_map` returns an array which is what it looks like you need returned since you are using `implode` on `$ids`.

So you need to have

```
$ids = array_map('intval', $_POST['id']);
```

Answer (score 1):

array_walk calls a function for every array, and takes function as parameter 0. I think you need to change:

`array_walk('intval', $_POST['id']);` to `array('intval', $_POST['id']);`

Answer (score 0):

Which line is line 36? Also, you seem to have an extra close parenthesis in the SQL statement. Furthermore, is the $_POST variable really an array?

Comment: yes it's an array. The html is `<input type="checkbox" name="id[]" value="{$id[$index]}" />`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have changed the order of arguments in `$ids = array_walk('intval', $_POST['id']);`? In my opinion it should be `$ids = array_walk($_POST['id'],'intval');`.